# How to solve the “You don't have permission to open the application” in Mac OS big sur?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, permission, big-sur, rosetta

When I want to open an app which I've downloaded outside of app store a pop up with the message of You dont have permission to open this app shows up.

[image]

My laptop is macbook pro 2020 m1 big sur version 11.1

[image]

I've checked of my user is the administrator or not and I found that I'm the only admin account on this laptop :

[image]

I've also tried to open app with rosetta but didn't work either and also tried to make all users able to read and write in the permissions of the app info .

[image]

I hope anyone could help me open such apps . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried a "right-click" with the mouse on the application icon, then in the contextual menu, you choose "Open", it should work after confirming your choice to open.

Comment: @Jean_JD It didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the issue may be the quarantine extended attribute and the Unix permissions. You can solve the issue by changing the permissions and deleting the extended attribute, running two commands in Terminal.

The first command changes the permissions to read, write and execute for the User and read and execute for Group and Other.

The second command strips the quarantine attribute.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/app.
 
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /path/to/app.
```