# You do not have permission to open the application “Anaconda-Navigator”

Tags: terminal, finder, applications, permission

It all started because I had an alias of Anaconda in the Applications folder, so I searched the Original Anaconda, moved using `Cmd` and drag it in the Applications folder, in order to have the Original one in the Applications Folder.
Now when I try to open the application I get the following message:

[image]

I have already checked and I (should) have the permission to open it since I'm the administrator:

[image]

I also tried to write from terminal the commands suggested here: [How to solve the “You don't have permission to open the application” in Mac OS big sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420364/how-to-solve-the-you-dont-have-permission-to-open-the-application-in-mac-os-b)

but nothing happened.

I also have the latest version of the software macOS Big Sur Version 11.6.5

Comment: It is not in the Applications folder - it is in Backup/Applications - also it is probably a link for a reason - best to leave it as a link.

Comment: so your advice would be to put it back where it was?

Comment: Yes - and probably try a reinstall to recreate the link

Comment: @mmmmmm I reinstalled it and (as expected) it worked out. If you want to make it as an answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information here. The app is not in /Applications but is on a backupdrive.

I would undo the moves you made or reinstall the application